# Avoid specifying Link/Input parameter in VC++ for static-link

Tags: visual-c++

Some famous libraries like wxwidgets does not need to specify Link/Input parameter in VC++ project, user just need to add the include directory and library directory. While some other libs you need to write xxx.lib/xxx.a in input parameter.

The benfit for no input parameter is VC++ could use correct lib when using DEBUG or RELEASE mode.

How to build libs(name libs) in the same way so it can be not necessary to specify input parameters?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`#pragma comment(lib)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx)

Comment: Also, you can use correct lib when using DEBUG or RELEASE mode using link/input parameter in VC++ project. I do it every day. Simply list different libs for debug and release configurations.

Comment: Putting LIB in project setting reduces code clutter

Comment: Thanks the problem resolved by #pragma